# Do all switches support VLAN tagging?

Tags: networking, switch

I want to buy a switch. I'm looking at one  [right now](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000N99BBC) on Amazon.

I also looked at the [specs](http://www.tp-link.com/lb/products/details/cat-4763_TL-SG1005D.html#specifications) for the model but it doesnt mention anything about VLAN tagging. Does it just not support it?

Comment: A quick look at your question gives an impression that you are asking for shopping advice which you aren't. Try rewording it

Answer (score 5):

This is an unmanaged switch. Meaning it doesn't have a way to configure the switch.
As configuration is needed to implement VLAN tagging (how else are you going to assign VLANs to ports?) it can't do VLAN.

The switch has to be managed. Any modern managed switch is able to do it. (I have encountered hundreds of different make/models/types of switches and I have never seen or even heard of a managed switch that couldn't do VLANs.)

That TPlink is a pretty good switch though, as far as unmanaged switches go. I'm actually typing this while being connected to its 8-port brother.

Answer (score 0):

Low price switches can't support VLAN tagging.

It's a task that requires a fast backbone and dedicated RAM.

If the vendor doesn't mention it, you can be sure that it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Only Enterprise / Midrange level switches support VLAN tagging. On the Comapny website for this model, they are not mentioned about VLAN tagging. Also for VLAN support, the switch should support more operation resources, but this model seems does not have.

Comment: Even cheap low-range switches support it, but it has to be a managed switch.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the switch you have linked supports it, as it is very uncommon for consumer-oriented network gear to support vlan.

However, I have seen switches being sold without "VLAN" appearing anywhere in the specs, but instead they list it as one of the standards it complies with. In most cases, what you want is support for VLAN tagging, which is 802.1Q

Answer (score 0):

No, not all switches support VLAN tagging.  Also, not all switches that support VLANs support tagging.

Some VLANs are port based - you can group ports on the switch as a VLAN, but the packets are not tagged.